# What is the difference between create and update with customizing mapping in knockout?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

```
 var repo = {
     desc: 'this is repo desc.',
     title: 'this is title.',
     job: { jobId: 1, description: 'job desc', status: 'Done', workAllowed: 'Yes' },
     fault: { faultId: 1, jobId: 1, faultDescription: 'some thing', removed: 1, },
 };

 var mappingSettings = {
        'job': {
            create: function (options) {
                options.data.status = "this has been created.";
                return options.data;
            },
            update: function(options) {
                options.data.status = "this has been updated";
                return options.data;
            }

        }
    };


    $(document).ready(function () {
        viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(repo, mappingSettings);
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    });
```

When i map the repo to viewModel using mappingSetting, i found viewModel.status:"this has been updated"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create is the first time when you create the model, update triggers if you map again.

http://jsfiddle.net/pHQ9t/

```
viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(repo, mappingSettings);


//Update again
ko.mapping.fromJS(repo, mappingSettings, viewModel);
```

Comment: I used viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(repo, mappingSettings); but it is  job.status is "this has been updated". means it is calling update too.

Comment: Yes first time it calls both Create and update, next time only update